# Decriptar arquivos db.crypt

Tags: java, android, api

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de decriptar arquivos com a extensão db.crypt em geral, na plataforma Android e existe alguma API que faça esse trabalho?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo esse [artigo](http://www.infocrime.com.br/2013/10/extracao-e-analise-de-mensagens-do-whatsapp/) os arquivos com a extensão `.db.crypt` utilizam uma chave de 192 *bits* AES, cujo valor é `346a23652a46392b4d73257c67317e352e3372482177652c`.

Para descriptografar você pode utilizar o OpenSSL que é pré-instalado no Linux, no Windows pode ser baixado [**aqui**](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Para descriptografar você pode usar o *shell-script* abaixo.

```
#!/bin/sh
openssl enc -d -aes-192-ecb \
    -in "$1" -out "$2" \
    -K 346a23652a46392b4d73257c67317e352e3372482177652c
```

Para usa-lo basta chamar:

```
~$ NomeDoScript.sh msgstore.db.crypt msgstore.db
```

---

Voltando ao assunto da pergunta, no Github existe um projeto chamado [`whassup`](https://github.com/jberkel/whassup) que faz exatamente o que você quer, nessa [página](https://github.com/jberkel/whassup/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/jberkel/whassup/crypto/DBDecryptor.java)(*DBDecryptor.java*) você poderá ver a rotina responsável por criptografar e descriptografar as mensagens.

Comment: QMechanic, mas ai o DB nao está encriptado

Comment: Entendi, no caso eu não preciso usar o Shell-Script, posso usar a classe do cara como base, certo?

Comment: @DaniloOliveira Correto. Postei o *script* apenas para complementar a resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!